# What exactly are size, ratio and line distance in Eagle PCB text tool?

Tags: eaglecad

What exatly does size quantify in the Eagle text tool?

Also, changing ratio and line distance does not seem have any affect. What exactly are they used for?

How do I know if I need to use vector, proportional or fixed Font?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure those are attributes that apply to text elements.  Size changes the height of the letters, Ratio changes the thickness of the letters, and distance (I think) affects the vertical space between lines (obviously only for multi-line texts), but context would help to clarify.

As far as vector, proportional, or fixed -- I just always use Vector to avoid surprises when it comes time to generate Gerber files. Seriously, I have no idea why it's not the default.

A picture is worth a thousand words, as they say. Experiment to see the effect of changing properties and how they interact.

[image]

Comment: Very nice visual summary! I, too, always use vector fonts, so that the Gerbers appear how I want them to.  On the other hand, in the Eagle forums there are some very vocal people that hate the look of the vector font, and so want to keep "proportional" as the default...

Comment: If you don't want proportional fonts in the design (I never do either), there is an option to override all fonts with vector. `Options->User Interface->Always vector font`. With that option enabled all fonts will be displayed as vector regardless of the font setting and will export as vector. There is also an option to make the setting persistent in the drawing which means if you open it on another computer that doesn't have the override setting enabled, the fonts will still appear as vector.